# Can I share a sql database alias in appharbor on multiple applications?

Tags: appharbor

I have two applications, both of them are deployed to appharbor, they both need to use the same sql database.

In one of them I simply use the database alias and appharbor injects the connection string into the connection strings part of web.config. What I can't see is how can I get appharbor to inject the same alias (with same connection string) into my second application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently a supported scenario, and I'm afraid you will have to manually configure the secondary app's connectionstring.